# Deposits in my Bank Account Program

Tags: java, account, bank

```
public void deposit(double amount)
{
 balance += amount;
}
```

This is what I'm calling in another class. I want to be able to deposit 100$ into this account.

```
Account acct1;

acct1 = new Account(500, "Joe", 1112);
```

What would I need to do in order to deposit into this account? I've tried different variations of this (below), but I'm confused as to what to do.

```
initBal = new deposit(100);
```

Help?

Comment: probably `this->balance += amount` first of all, you're treating your `deposit` method as object itself, which is probably wrong.

Comment: `new deposit(100)` is incorrect in this case because `deposit` is a method, not a class.

Comment: side note: it's actually pretty dangerous to use `float` or `double` for money in most languages, including Java. these data types are prone to floating-point double rounding errors during division, and the errors are worse with bigger numbers (more money == more erratic math). it's recommended to store the money as cents rather than dollars, in a `long int`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for what it appears you want to do is:

```
Account acct1;                           //Creating a reference of type Account
acct1 = new Account(500, "Joe", 1112);   //Instantiating a new Account object, 
                                         //giving a reference to that object to acct1
acct1.deposit(100);                      //Calling the deposit method in class Account
                                         //On the object referred to by acct1
```

More generally, to call a method on an object (of a type that has that method):

```
<object_reference>.<method_name>(<parameter 1>, <parameter 2>, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `Account` object stores your initial balance and that your `deposit` method increase it:

Example:

```
public class Account{

    private Double balance;

    public Account(Double initBalance, String name, int number){
        this.balance = initBalance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

}
```

Then when you create an instance of Account `acct1 = new Account(500, "Joe", 1112);`

Then, to increase the balance of your account, you have to call the deposit method that is inside your instance of `Account`

```
 acct1.deposit(amount)
```